# Select box verify with javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to ask users to verify their select option choice by using a javascript alert. If the user clicks continue then it will delete the choice, if they click cancel they will return to page.
I have the php code for a drop down done, so it will be populated with code from a database and the user can then select a value to delete. I dont know what the javascript must be to ask a verification.

My php code so far is:

```
<select>
<option selected name="offer">Click here to choose item</option>
<?
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items";
$res = $dbi->dbDo($sql);
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) ) { 
print_r('<option>'.$row['name'].'</option>');
}
?>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Delete" class="button-delete" onClick="submit()"></input>
```

So now there should be a javascript function called submit, but before they submit a confirmation must happen.

Thanks

Comment: you want to deleted it from database?

Comment: Yes, The delete part is ok. I just want to allow the user to Confirm that he has made the right choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function submit()
{
     var sel=document.getElementByName("offer").value;
     var r=confirm("do you really want to delete the selected option");
     var xmlhttp;
     if(r==true)
     {
         if(window.xmlHttpRequest)
         {
             xmlhttp=new xmlHttpRequest();
         }
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
         {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
            {
                 alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
         }
         xmlhttp.open("GET","hello.php?option="+sel,true);
         xmlhttp.send();
     }
}
```

now here the file hello.php which will delete the selected option

```
<?
$sql = "delete FROM items where itemvalue=".$_REQUEST["option"];
if($sql)
{
   echo("item deleted");
}
?>
```

the echo in this php file will be shown as the alert.

click it as answer if you like it

Comment: Thank you so much this helped. I did have to change the 
var sel=document.getElementByName("offer").value; to var sel=document.getElementsByName("offer").value; Not sure why that was but it worked. Thank you

Comment: have some basic knowledge buddy , this was a spoon feed